# .Net Dockerizing excluding build stage in the dockerfile

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, kubernetes, macbookpro-touch-bar

I am new to docker and AKS, I am working on a .Net project that is migrated from .Net core 3.1 to .Net 6 , I am trying to containerize and deploy to AKS. First i wanted to test in the local machine so i had setup docker in the macbook m1 and followed this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/docker-quickstart?view=vsmac-2022 to create a dockerfile, I am able to run the dockerfile from Visual Studio if i follow the steps given in the link but if i run **docker compose** command from terminal i am getting issues with SDK version, however what i am trying to achieve is remove the build stage and directly run the .net application as the build stage is taken care by Jenkins and the DLL is placed in a folder

**Here is the complete dockerfile with all the stages**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY DockerDemo/DockerDemo.csproj DockerDemo/
RUN dotnet restore "DockerDemo/DockerDemo.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockerDemo"
RUN dotnet build "DockerDemo.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockerDemo.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerDemo.dll"]
```

I modified dockerfile excluding build stage, I am taking DLL file from a **"lib/net6.0"** that is built by jenkins and placed in this folder

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:6.0 AS base
COPY ["lib/net6.0","/src/"]
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM base as final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=base /src/ .
ENTRYPOINT["dotnet","DockerDemo.dll"]
```

If i build the dockerfile the image is getting created but when i run I am getting following error

> unhandled exception system.io.filenotfoundexception could not load
> file or assembly 'NLog, Version=.5.0.0.0

The project is using NLog.Web.ASPNetCore 5.1.4 version, i tried downgrading it to 5.0.0 but i am still getting the same error, i also tried adding just NLog 5.0.0 package but no luck

As i said i am new to Docker and also to the .net development on macbook

**My Questions**

**Q1) Is it possible to exclude the build stage in dockerfile and directly run**

**Q2) Does the macbook m1 completely supports .Net Core and .Net 6 development so that it can be deployed to AKS via Jenkins pipeline**

Comment: You need to publish the project before copying to docker.

Comment: Thank you for responding @CodingMytra , So the publish statement has to be there in Dockerfile?

Comment: No outside docker. Output of publish folder should be copied to docker.

Comment: Yes that is the published one @CodingMytra

Comment: Have you verified the NLog assembly exists in the files that you're copying into the image?

Comment: Thank you @CodingMytra and Matt . Was in an impression that dotnet pack is equivalent to publish but i think dockerfile looks for published files using dotnet publish, I did publish and referred to the DLL from that folder and it worked. Can you please let me know Does the macbook m1 completely supports .Net Core and .Net 6 development so that it can be deployed to AKS via Jenkins pipeline